# Not able to register preferences on mozilla using registerFactoryLocation

Tags: javascript, preferences, xpcom

I m XPCOM component for registering the preferences on mozilla firefox but it is not getting reflected in prefs.js file.
Anything more i need to use apart from registerFactoryLocation code....
Thanks in advance :)

ya sure,I have developed an XPI,in that in comonents folder I have added a mymanager.js file. In that I have creted a component using the code like.......... http://kb.mozillazine.org/Implementing_XPCOM_components_in_JavaScript  but this code does not able to add the _prority preferece to mozilla firefox preferences(prefs.js) file. I need to do anything more to register the preference...

Comment: Your question is rather vague.  Editing it to include code that isn't working and a better description of what your problem is would help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Although your extension can register preferences, prefs.js only contains changed preferences, so they won't automatically appear there.